# How do I utilize printed coordinates from the system console to place an object?

Tags: python, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have over 50 vertex groups that I have on my mesh. I am using a script to locate the world position of a vertex group that is then printed into the system console. I am wondering how do I grab the printed world coordinates from the system console in a python script to place the cursor at those specific world coordinates? And is this a process that can repeated looped through multiple vertex groups?

```
import bpy
import bmesh


obj = bpy.context.collection.all_objects["Gazelle"] #object name 

vertex_group = obj.vertex_groups["stomach"] #vertex group name 

vg_index = vertex_group.index

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

bm = bmesh.new()

bm.from_object( obj, depsgraph )

deform = bm.verts.layers.deform.active

world_matrix = obj.matrix_world

for vert in [v for v in bm.verts if vg_index in v[deform]]:
    # vertex coordinate in object space
    co = vert.co
    # vertex coordinate in world space
    world_co = world_matrix @ co
    print(co, world_co)
```

Comment: Why on earth would you go through the system console first? Why not just place the 3-D cursor from this code instead of trying to run a second script on console output?

Comment: whenever i try to go through the code it says there is a context error.

Comment: It would be a good idea to ask about that problem then. Currently this question is about an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: thats fair, will ask new question